# Bricolage: how to check if a story has a particular field?

Tags: perl, content-management-system

In the Bricolage CMS, what is the way to check whether a story has a particular field (in this case called 'teaser') set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean in a template? If you want to know if a story has a field in a template, you can use either the `get_field()` or the `get_value()` method. Use `get_field()` if you just want to know if the field is present, as it returns a [Bric::Biz::Element::Field](http://www.bricolagecms.org/docs/current/api/Bric%3a%3aBiz%3a%3aElement%3a%3aField) object (I assume Mason templating here):

```
if (my $field = $element->get_field('teaser')) {
    $m->print('<p>', $field->get_value, "</p>\n");
}
```

If you want to know if a field has a value, you use `get_value()`:

```
if (my $val = $element->get_value('teaser')) {
    $m->print("<p>$val</p>\n");
}
```

That method will return `undef` if there is no field object, and the value of the field object if it exists. Note that if the value is an empty string or `0`, nothing will be printed there, either.

But it's important to note that Bricolage documents are organized in a tree structure of elements. The best way to create templates is one for each container element. The above example, might be in a top-level "story" element template, where `$element` will be the top-level element itself. But if your "teater" field is in a subelement, say "Metadata", you'll want to create a "metadata" element template with the above code, and call it from your story element template, like so:

```
$burner->display_element('metadata');
```

See [Bric::Templates](http://bricolagecms.org/docs/current/api/Bric%3a%3aTemplates) for an introduction to Bricolage templating and the API.

HTH,

David